# Divide rows in different Sections

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have following arrays which one is for the football matches and one is for the sections:

```
sectionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[sectionsArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Barclays Premier League",@"league", @"england.png",@"img", nil]];
[sectionsArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Primera Division",@"league", @"spain.png",@"img", nil]];


array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


[array1 addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Tottenham",@"hometeam", @"Everton",@"awayteam", @"1", @"homescore", @"0", @"awayscore", nil]];
[array1 addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Manchester Utd",@"hometeam", @"Fulham",@"awayteam", @"2", @"homescore", @"2", @"awayscore", nil]];
```

How can i choose which match should be in what sections?

right now all matches is doubled in each sections like this:
[image]

Comment: Add the requirement to the question (which rows *should* be in which section), and show the code you're currently using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating single array for matches you should create two array's

```
[arrayBarclay addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Tottenham",@"hometeam", @"Everton",@"awayteam", @"1", @"homescore", @"0", @"awayscore", nil]];

[arraySpanish addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Team1",@"hometeam", @"Team2",@"awayteam", @"2", @"homescore", @"2", @"awayscore", nil]];
```

And then load appropriate arrays in your tableView datasource methods

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
     if(section==0)
     {
        return [arrayBarclay count];
     }
     return [arraySpanish count];
  }
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *cellidentifier= @"cellIdentifier";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];
  if (cell==Nil)
  {
         cell  = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellidentifier] autorelease];
  }
  if(indexPath.section==0
  {
       cell.detailTextLabel.text= [arrayBarclay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  }
  else
  {
       cell.detailTextLabel.text= [arraySpanish objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  }
     return cell;  
}
```

Comment: What do i then do with my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Since i need to use 2 arrays in there?

Comment: yes you can check for section in your cellForRowAtUndexPath:. See my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

```
sectionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

sectionOneRows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[sectionOneRows addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Barclays Premier League",@"league", @"england.png",@"img", nil]];
[sectionOneRows addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Primera Division",@"league", @"spain.png",@"img", nil]];


sectionTwoRows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[sectionTwoRows addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Tottenham",@"hometeam", @"Everton",@"awayteam", @"1", @"homescore", @"0", @"awayscore", nil]];
[sectionTwoRows addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Manchester Utd",@"hometeam", @"Fulham",@"awayteam", @"2", @"homescore", @"2", @"awayscore", nil]];

[sectionsArray addObject:sectionOneRows];
[sectionsArray addObject:sectionTwoRows];
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath method,

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```